# Ad image width isn't right (%)

Tags: html, css

Not sure what the problem is. It looks right in dreamweaver, but when I preview in Firefox or IE (latest versions) it shows the width of the ad image as being really small.

I'm trying to make the width a % with the height: auto so that it will resize with the page. But that's not happening. It stays the same size.

Here's the CSS:

```
#ad2 {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #5C7689;
    background-image: url(images/bg3%20top2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

#ad2 img {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="ad2"><img src="images/blank ad.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: I can't replicate your issue http://jsfiddle.net/soqLsL0c/ .... works fine

Comment: Seems fine to me in FF and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0fm5uxgs/

Comment: It might have something to do with what the browser thinks is the parent of div#ad2. It might also help if you give div#ad2 a height property or set overflow to auto.

Comment: Tested it in IE and Chrome... Seems to be fine; You could, however, add a Screenshot of the issue within your browser